# English documentary with German subtitles

Tags: learning, resource

It is easy to find German documentaries with English subtitles. But I am looking for English voiced documentaries with German subtitles. I find this makes it easier to learn new German words.

Any ways to get English-voiced documentaries with German subtitles?

Any websites? Any links on Youtube?

Comment: What [DVD regions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dvd_region) do you have access to?

Comment: Do you receive "educational channels"? If yes, check if your TV system is capable of switching language/subtitle.

Comment: Thanks. Anything for people with no Tv or dvd player. Any websites or youtube links?

Answer (score 4):

Many German DVDs (or similar) of anglophone movies come with a German and English audio track and at least German subtitles. You should always check the specifications though. Though I have no experience with documentaries in specific, I do not see why this should not hold for those.

The only annoyance might be that you have to import these from Germany and may have to struggle with region codes (which may be easy to legally circumvent in your legislation though).